# Improving the performance of text cleanup on a dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas, nltk, apply

I have a df:

```
id    text
1     This is a good sentence
2     This is a sentence with a number: 2015
3     This is a third sentence
```

I have a text cleaning function:

```
def clean(text):
    lettersOnly = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ', text)
    tokens = word_tokenize(lettersOnly.lower())
    stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stops]
    tokensPOS = pos_tag(tokens)
    tokensLemmatized = []
    for w in tokensPOS:
        tokensLemmatized.append(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w[0], get_wordnet_pos(w[1])))
    clean = " ".join(tokensLemmatized)
    return clean
```

`get_wordnet_pos()` is this:

```
def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):
    if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return wordnet.NOUN
```

I am applying `extractFeatures()` to a pandas column and creating a new column with the results:

```
df['cleanText'] = df['text'].apply(clean)
```

Resulting df:

```
id    cleanText
1     good sentence
2     sentence number
3     third sentence
```

The loop time appears to grow exponentially. For example, using `%%timeit`, applying it to five rows runs at 17 ms per loop. 300 rows runs at 800 ms per loop. 500 rows runs at 1.26 s per loop.

I altered it by instantiating `stops` and `WordNetLemmatizer()` outside of the function since those only need to be called once.

```
stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
def clean(text):
    lettersOnly = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ', text)
    tokens = word_tokenize(lettersOnly.lower())
    tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stops]
    tokensPOS = pos_tag(tokens)
    tokensLemmatized = []
    for w in tokensPOS:
        tokensLemmatized.append(lem.lemmatize(w[0], get_wordnet_pos(w[1])))
    clean = " ".join(tokensLemmatized)
    return clean
```

Running `%prun -l 10` on the `apply` line resulted in this table:

```
         672542 function calls (672538 primitive calls) in 2.798 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 211 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     4097    0.727    0.000    0.942    0.000 perceptron.py:48(predict)
     4500    0.584    0.000    0.584    0.000 {built-in method nt.stat}
     3500    0.243    0.000    0.243    0.000 {built-in method nt._isdir}
    14971    0.157    0.000    0.178    0.000 {method 'sub' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
    57358    0.129    0.000    0.155    0.000 perceptron.py:250(add)
     4105    0.117    0.000    0.201    0.000 {built-in method builtins.max}
   184365    0.084    0.000    0.084    0.000 perceptron.py:58(<lambda>)
     4097    0.057    0.000    0.213    0.000 perceptron.py:245(_get_features)
      500    0.038    0.000    1.220    0.002 perceptron.py:143(tag)
     2000    0.034    0.000    0.068    0.000 ntpath.py:471(normpath)
```

It looks like the perceptron tagger is, predictably, taking a lot of resources, but I'm not sure how to streamline it. In addition, I'm not sure where `nt.stat` or `nt._isdir` is being called.

How should I alter the function or apply method to increase performance? Is this function a candidate for Cython or Numba?

Comment: Can't say without your data and expected output.

Comment: Added sample input data and the result of the cleaning function. I am getting the proper output - the question is more about how to get that proper output quicker.

Comment: Interesting. Does order of the words matter? I'm guessing yes?

Comment: yes, because `cleanedText` is later sent into vectorizers to collect ngrams, frequencies, tf-idf weights ,etc.

Comment: I see the most obvious point of improvement is to reduce `get_wordnet_pos` to a `str` `defaultdict`.

Comment: Besides this, you could skip the regex step, because `word_tokenize` will tokenise punctuations and other special chars separately, which stop words will then prune provided you update it in advance.

Comment: Besides this, what is `pos_tag(tokens)` doing?

Comment: Or, you could just you `str.split` to the same effect. It doesn't sacrifice much, but the speedup would be good.

Comment: `pos_tag(tokens)` is tagging each token with the part-of-speech so it can be fed into the lemmatizer. it's nltk's perceptron tagger `from nltk import pos_tag`

Comment: Finally, I'm not sure what `" ".join(tokensLemmatized)` is doing - it is a list of tuples! If not, just return then list and the call `df.str.applymap(" ".join)` - should be faster.

Comment: thanks - i will give your suggestions a try! some new concepts in there for me (i.e. `defaultdict`)

Comment: Shall I write an answer?

Comment: sounds good to me!

Comment: `tokensLemmatized` is actually a regular list of strings. so `join` is joining those strings back into the cleaned sentence. it looks like it should be a list of tuples because of the part-of-speech tag, but that tag gets dropped off.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't see the call to `lem.lemmatize` earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first obvious point of improvement I see here is that the entire `get_wordnet_pos` function should be reducible to a dictionary lookup:

```
def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):
    if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return wordnet.NOUN
```

Instead of this, initialise a `defaultdict` from the `collections` package:

```
import collections 
get_wordnet_pos = collections.defaultdict(lambda: wordnet.NOUN)
get_wordnet_pos.update({'J' : wordnet.ADJ,  
                        'V' : wordnet.VERB, 
                        'N' : wordnet.NOUN, 
                        'R' : wordnet.ADV })
```

You will then access the lookup like this:

```
get_wordnet_pos[w[1][0]]
```

Next, you could consider pre-compiling your regex pattern if it is to be used in multiple places. The speedup you get isn't as much, but it all matters.

```
pattern = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
```

Inside your function, you'd call:

```
pattern.sub(' ', text)
```

OTOH, if you are aware of where your text is coming from and have some idea of what you might and might not see, you can pre-compile a list of characters and instead use `str.translate`, which is much much faster than a clunky regex based substitution:

```
tab = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys("1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]|\'\":;,<.>/?\\~`", '')) # pre-compiled use once substitution table (keep this outside the function)

text = 'hello., hi! lol, what\'s up'
new_text = text.translate(tab) # this would run inside your function

print(new_text)

'hello hi lol whats up'
```

Furthermore, I'd say `word_tokenize` is overkill - what you do is get rid of special characters anyway, so you lose all the benefits of `word_tokenize`, which really makes a difference with punctuation and the like. You could just choose to fall back on `text.split()`.

Finally, skip the `clean = " ".join(tokensLemmatized)` step. Just return the list, and then call `df.applymap(" ".join)` in the final step.

I leave the benchmarking to you.

Comment: Thanks so much - extremely helpful. For the defaultdict, it throws an error saying `TypeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object is not callable`. Apart from that, what you're saying about the replacements and splitting makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @CameronTaylor There's a small mistake. You would call the dict like `get_wordnet_pos[...]`, not with `(...)`. Will edit my answer.

Comment: another quirk with that may be that in the original function, the tags are found by `startswith`. Is there a way to implement that into the `defaultdict`? Because at the moment I believe it's treating most things as nouns since a lot of the tags are more than just one letter.

Comment: @CameronTaylor Oh, my bad. I thought that was understood. Actually, you call the dictionary like this: `get_wordnet_pos[w[1][0]]` where `w[1]` is the word and `w[1][0]` is the first char.

Comment: no, i'm just dense. thank you, again. i'll accept your answer while I work through the rest of your suggestions. already seeing speed improvement.

Comment: @CameronTaylor Best of luck to you. Let me know how it works out.